# Property 'date' does not exist on type '{} | { date: string; }'

Tags: javascript, typescript, query-string

I still new to typescript and types in general, but this error is really confusing me. I am using the npm modules `query-string` to parse a query string into a object of key/value pairs. But i am not sure what the best way of type setting the return value. `query-string` using the `.parse()` method will either return a object of key/value pairs OR a empty object.

**Example:**

```
queryString: { date: string } | {} =  queryString.parse(location.search);
```

When i trying to accessing a property using `queryString.date` i get this error: `Property 'date' does not exist on type '{} | { date: string; }'`

I am sure i am missing something basic here i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to access the property; transpiler *does not know* if you want to use the object as an empty object or the object with date.

There are several ways to tackle the issue:

1: `queryString: { date?: string } =  queryString.parse(location.search);`
It will, in essence, mean that the object can have the `date` property but it is not necessary. Use this in case you want to have `queryString.date` to be either proper `date` or `undefined`

2: Surround your usage with if
It's as simple as that.

```
if(queryString.date !== undefined) {
   const date = queryString.date;
   //... Do stuff
}
```

3: (Not advised) If for any other reason you are just not interested if it's there or not, you can force transpiler to treat it as one or the other by `as` keyworord

```
const myDate: Date = (queryString as {date: Date}).date
```

Comment: So what you are saying because the object MIGHT be empty the transpiler treats it as if it IS empty?

Comment: Because types are duck-typed; Transpiler treats the object as *both* when using it without any check: `Property 'date' does not exist on type '{} | { date: string; }'` because it can not exist and exist at the same time. That's why you either mark it as optional with `?` or you check for undefined (Which, in essence, will decide IF it is `{}` or `{date:Date}`

Answer (score 1):

Just make **date** an optional property.

```
queryString: { date?: string } =  queryString.parse(location.search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are declaring the queryString property also as an empty object {}. And simply sayed, `{}` has no property `date`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set anything -- TypeScript will infer the type automatically based on the return value.

```
queryString =  queryString.parse(location.search);
```

And what TypeScript is telling is true. If something is either `{}` or `{date: string}`, there's no guarantee that `.date` will exist. TypeScript respects that and errors out appropriately. It's desired behavior.